# How to insert element after the iterator position

Tags: c++, stl

std::list.insert inserts an element before the iterator position. How can I insert an element after an iterator position.

Answer (score 21):

that's what `list::insert` does. Just increment your iterator before inserting your value:

```
if (someIterator != someList.end()) {
    someIterator++;
}
someList.insert(someIterator, someValue);
```

Comment: Also, remember that this works because `someList.insert(someList.end(), someValue);` is valid.

Comment: or: `someList.insert(std::next(someIterator), someValue);`

Answer (score 1):

Use the function:

`itr = mylist.insert_after(Itr, value)`

It will insert the `value` after the position pointed by `itr`.

Comment: This is only for std::forward_list, not std::list.